# Some turtle functions not working on new turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So i have created a new turtle by doing `bassel = turtle.Turtle()`, however, some functions such as `tracer()` and `onkeypress()` just don't work, I get an error saying `'Turtle' object has no attribute 'tracer'` or `'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkeypress'`...

But as soon as I replace *bassel* by *turtle* it works

So for instance, `bassel.onkeypress()` doesn't work ('Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkeypress')

But if I put `turtle.onkeypress()`, it works perfectly.

Here's some part of the code

```
bassel = turtle.Turtle()
bassel.tracer(0)
bassel.hideturtle()
```

Answer (score 1):

Right.  Those functions are not attributes of a SPECIFIC turtle object, they are services offered by the turtle module.  Just use `turtle.tracer` and `turtle.onkeypress`.